# How to retrieve object id from ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

It would be probably fairy simple solution, but i can't figure it out on my own. So, basically i have classic model of Database with Book, Author and Publisher. And the only problem i have is with the book one. To add the book i am using ModelChoiceField to choose Publisher. But after trying to save this form I'm still getting error that "Column 'publisher_id' cannot be null". The choice field is showing only name of publisher, and i don't know how to get ID of this publisher to let it be added to this book as publisher's ID. I'd be gratefull for any help.

models.py:

```
    class Author(models.Model):
        firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s %s' % (self.firstName, self.lastName)


    class Publisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        year = models.DateField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


    class Book(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        publishYear = models.DateField()
        isbnNumber = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=0)
        author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
        publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

forms.py:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Author.objects.all())
    publisher = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Publisher.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'isbnNumber', 'publishYear']
```

view.py:

```
def book_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()

    return render(request, 'book_add.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Same, as in AjayGupta said, to change fields ='__all__'. I'm getting error that Author object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`author` is a many-to-many, so you need to use `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

However I don't know why you've redefined those fields in the first place. ModelChoiceField is already the default for a foreign key field. Remove those two definitions, and add `author` and `publisher` into the `fields` list.